# How to find a variable string in many text files and output into CSV file the text file name and the found string?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Below content is in all files with varying time value.

```
[ boomer ]  elapsed:            00:00:02
```

I want the output to be as below to a CSV file. I tried to check for the string elapsed, but output is not coming properly in Windows command line.

```
logfile1 - Copy (2).txt,00:00:02
logfile1 - Copy.txt,00:00:34
logfile1.txt,00:00:09
New folder\logfile1 - Copy (2).txt,00:00:02
```

Sample text in the files are:

**logfile1 - Copy (2).txt:**

```
[ boomer ]  elapsed:            00:00:02
```

**logfile1 - Copy.txt:**

```
[ boomer]  elapsed:            00:00:34
```

**logfile1.txt:**

```
[ boomer]  elapsed:            00:00:09
```

**New folder\logfile1 - Copy (2).txt:**

```
[ boomer]  elapsed:            00:00:02
```

**New folder\logfile1 - Copy.txt:**

```
[ boomer]  elapsed:            00:00:34
```

**New folder\logfile1.txt:**

```
[ boomer]  elapsed:            00:00:09
```

Below is the code which I tried to achieve the result:

```
set /P filename=Please enter csv file name:
echo file,time>%filename%.csv
findstr /s /x "elapsed" .txt >> %filename%.txt
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set INTEXTFILE=test.txt
set OUTTEXTFILE=temp.txt
set SEARCHTEXT=:
set REPTEXT=,
set OUTPUTLINE=
for /f "tokens=1, delims=¶" %%A in ('"type %INTEXTFILE%"') do (
    SET string=%%A
    setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    SET modified=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%REPTEXTT%!
    echo !modified! >> %OUTTEXTFILE%
    endlocal
)
```

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Below is he code which i tried to achieve the result.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `[ boomer]` without a space left of closing square bracket is a typing mistake and all files contain `[ boomer ]`. However, this difference makes it not possible (easily) to use spaces/tabs as delimiters on processing the lines from the files containing `elapsed:` and the time data of interest.

Therefore the Windows standard console application **FINDSTR** is used to search for *.txt files containing a line with `elapsed:`. The output of **FINDSTR** on calling with

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /L /S /C:elapsed: *.txt
```

is for the provided example files and data

```
logfile1 - Copy (2).txt:[ boomer ]  elapsed:            00:00:02
logfile1 - Copy.txt:[ boomer]  elapsed:            00:00:34
logfile1.txt:[ boomer]  elapsed:            00:00:09
New folder\logfile1.txt:[ boomer]  elapsed:            00:00:09
New folder\logfile1 - Copy.txt:[ boomer]  elapsed:            00:00:34
New folder\logfile1 - Copy (2).txt:[ boomer ]  elapsed:            00:00:02
```

But if file pattern at end of **FINDSTR** command is with a full path like on using

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /L /S /C:elapsed: "C:\Temp\*.txt"
```

the file names are output also with full path

```
C:\Temp\logfile1 - Copy (2).txt:[ boomer ]  elapsed:            00:00:02
C:\Temp\logfile1 - Copy.txt:[ boomer]  elapsed:            00:00:34
C:\Temp\logfile1.txt:[ boomer]  elapsed:            00:00:09
C:\Temp\New folder\logfile1.txt:[ boomer]  elapsed:            00:00:09
C:\Temp\New folder\logfile1 - Copy.txt:[ boomer]  elapsed:            00:00:34
C:\Temp\New folder\logfile1 - Copy (2).txt:[ boomer ]  elapsed:            00:00:02
```

and containing now also a colon after drive letter.

This difference must be taken into account on parsing the output lines of **FINDSTR** as done in the two batch files below designed both for a source directory on a local or a network drive with a drive letter.

Batch code for getting file names with a path relative to current directory:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Delete the output file if existing already in current directory
rem for example from a previous execution of this batch file.
if exist OutputList.csv del /F OutputList.csv
goto CreateCSV

rem Execute console application FINDSTR to search in current directory and
rem all subdirectories for files with file extension TXT containing a line
rem with "elapsed:". FINDSTR outputs the file name with relative path and
rem the line containing the searched string with a colon as separator.

rem As each found line contains also a colon after "elapsed" the colon
rem is used as delimiter to split up each line into 3 substrings (tokens)
rem assigned to the loop variables A, B and C. Loop variable A holds the
rem file name (with relative path), loop variable B holds the line from
rem file up to end of "elapsed" and loop variable C holds the remaining
rem string on the line with last 8 characters being the time data.

rem A second FOR loop is used to trim preceding and trailing spaces/tabs
rem from the substring with the time data.

rem For each line returned by FINDSTR a row is appended to the output CSV
rem file with the file name and the time data. If the file name contains
rem itself a comma, the file name is enclosed in double quotes to produce
rem a valid CSV file also for such an unusual file name.

:CreateCSV
for /F "tokens=1,2* delims=:" %%A in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /L /S /C:elapsed: *.txt 2^>nul') do (
    for /F %%I in ("%%C") do set "TimeData=%%I"
    set "FileName=%%A"
    if "!FileName:,=!" == "!FileName!" (
        echo !FileName!,!TimeData!>>OutputList.csv
    ) else (
        echo "!FileName!",!TimeData!>>OutputList.csv
    )
)
endlocal
```

And a similar batch code with getting files names with absolute path:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define source directory. Use %CD% instead of C:\Temp to use the
rem current directory on running the batch file or use %~dp0 to use
rem the directory of the batch file as source directory.
set "SourceDirectory=C:\Temp"

rem Make sure the source directory path does not end with a backslash
rem and check if the source directory exists at all, otherwise exit.
if "%SourceDirectory:~-1%" == "\" set "SourceDirectory=%SourceDirectory:~0,-1%"
if not exist "%SourceDirectory%\*" goto :EOF

rem Delete the output file if existing already in source directory
rem for example from a previous execution of this batch file.
set "OutputFile=%SourceDirectory%\OutputList.csv"
if exist "%OutputFile%" del /F "%OutputFile%"
goto CreateCSV

rem Execute console application FINDSTR to search in source directory and
rem all subdirectories for files with file extension TXT containing a line
rem with "elapsed:". FINDSTR outputs the file name with absolute path and
rem the line containing the searched string with a colon as separator.

rem As each found line contains also a colon after "elapsed" the colon
rem is used as delimiter to split up each line into 4 substrings (tokens)
rem assigned to the loop variables A, B, C and D. Loop variable A holds the
rem drive letter, loop variable B the path and file name, loop variable C
rem holds the line from file up to end of "elapsed" and loop variable D
rem holds the remaining string on the line with last 8 characters being
rem the time data.

rem A second FOR loop is used to trim preceding and trailing spaces/tabs
rem from the substring with the time data.

rem For each line returned by FINDSTR a row is appended to the output CSV
rem file with the file name and the time data. If the file name contains
rem itself a comma, the file name is enclosed in double quotes to produce
rem a valid CSV file also for such an unusual file name.

:CreateCSV
for /F "tokens=1-3* delims=:" %%A in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /L /S /C:elapsed: "%SourceDirectory%\*.txt" 2^>nul') do (
    for /F %%I in ("%%D") do set "TimeData=%%I"
    set "FileName=%%A:%%B"
    if "!FileName:,=!" == "!FileName!" (
        echo !FileName!,!TimeData!>>"%OutputFile%"
    ) else (
        echo "!FileName!",!TimeData!>>"%OutputFile%"
    )
)
endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

And read also the Microsoft article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `>>` and `2>nul`.

Redirection operator `>` must be escaped within command **FOR** with `^` to be applied on execution of **FINDSTR** and not being interpreted as redirection for command **FOR** at wrong position which would result in a syntax error. Redirection of **STDERR** with `2>nul` to device **NUL** is used to suppress the error message output by **FINDSTR** if it could not find any *.txt file containing `elapsed:`.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to sort the second column of the CSV in descending? I tried with sort /+2 csvfilename. But it did not work for me.

Comment: I provided 2 batch code solutions. Which one should be adapted to have the lines sorted according to time data? After giving the answer on this simple question, take the Stack Overflow's [2-minute tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) while waiting for an adapted batch code. I know already how to get the lines sorted by time data into the CSV file, but I don't code and publish it until getting response from you.